# matching pair of employees in a same department

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make a list of employees working in a same department like:

| employeeName | department | employeeName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tim | 2 | kim |
| Tim | 2 | Jim |
| Kim | 2 | Tim |
| Kim | 2 | Jim |
| Jim | 2 | Kim |
| Jim | 2 | Tim |
| Aim | 3 | Sim |
| Sim | 3 | Aim |

But the only thing i can do for now is:

```
SELECT emp_name, dept_code
  FROM employee
 WHERE dept_code IN (SELECT dept_code FROM employee);
```

| employeeName | department |
| --- | --- |
| Tim | 2 |
| Kim | 2 |
| Jim | 2 |
| Aim | 3 |
| Sim | 3 |

How can I make a list pairing with the employee working in a same department? thanks gurus...

Comment: Can you please add what have you tried as a query, and what output would you want to get?

Comment: Idk how to write since I'm trying to approach to what i want through various tries but this is one of the thing i tried: 
```
SELECT EMP_NAME, DEPT_CODE
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE DEPT_CODE IN (SELECT DEPT_CODE FROM EMPLOYEE);
```

Comment: Is the first table of your question the intended outcome? Are you really sure it should or even must look like that? Or do you just want to get a list of employees per department? It makes a very strange impression your result contains every pair twice.

Comment: and the expected output is ...? (not comment, but edit question please)

Comment: @JonasMetzler The first table is what I want like Tim is working with Kim in dept2, Tim is working with Jim in dept2 vice versa

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan the first table is the output i want

Answer (score 3):

To first point that out: I dislike your idea to create such a result listing "pairs" twice and would prefer another, easier query whose results would be better to read. I will come back to this later in this answer.

But anyway, if you really want to produce the outcome you have shown, we can do this with `CROSS JOIN`. This builds all combinations of employees.

In the `WHERE` clause, we will set the conditions that they must work in the same department, but have different names:

```
SELECT 
e1.emp_name AS employeeName, 
e1.dept_code AS department, 
e2.emp_name AS employeeName
FROM 
employee e1
CROSS JOIN employee e2
WHERE 
e1.dept_code = e2.dept_code
AND e1.emp_name <> e2.emp_name
ORDER BY e1.dept_code, e1.emp_name, e2.emp_name;
```

To come back to the idea to make this much easier and better to read: We can just use `LISTAGG` with `GROUP BY` to produce a comma-separated list of employees per department. I highly recommend to use this approach due to much better performance and readability.

This query will do on new Oracle DB's:

```
SELECT dept_code, 
LISTAGG (emp_name,',') AS employees
FROM employee
GROUP BY dept_code;
```

On older Oracle DB's, we need to add a `WITHIN GROUP` clause:

```
SELECT dept_code, 
LISTAGG (emp_name,',') 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY emp_name) AS employees
FROM employee
GROUP BY dept_code;
```

This will produce following result for your sample data:

| DEPT_CODE | EMPLOYEES |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Jim,Kim,Tim |
| 3 | Aim,Sim |

Here we can try out these things: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GkmMXRom)

Answer (score 0):

You will get all the pairs (A,B) and (B,A) of employees in the same department at the exclusion of all (A,A) with:

```
SELECT e1.emp_name AS first_emp_name, e1.dept_code, e2.emp_name AS second_emp_name
  FROM employee e1
JOIN employee e2 ON e1.dept_code = e2.dept_code AND e1.emp_name <> e2.emp_name ;
```